# Appium-my console shows seesion not created exception-How to resolve

Tags: java, exception, appium, appium-android, appium-java

i am using Appium V1.22.3 version

Script

```
package appium;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class appium {
    public static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "13");
cap.setCapability("udid", "3200c3acb4e9758b");
cap.setCapability("devicemName", "Galaxy M13");
cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.google.android.calculator");
cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.calculator.calculator");
URL url=new URL("http:0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub/");
driver =new AndroidDriver(cap);
System.out.println("Done");
        
        }

}
```

i have watched multiple videos in yputube but still not yet issue resolved.can anyone suggest me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Appium is basically HTTP server.
In order to use the webdriver/client - you need a working server.
You can start the server locally with the following code:

```
  public static void startService_3(){
        AppiumServiceBuilder appiumServiceBuilder=new AppiumServiceBuilder()
                .withAppiumJS(new File("C:\\Users\\" + "{user}" + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\lib\\main.js"))
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "warn")
                .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1")
                .usingAnyFreePort()
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SHELL);
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(appiumServiceBuilder);
        service.start();
    }
```

The pom.xml I'm using contains:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please let me know if it helps you.